# How can I successfully install Ubuntu on Asus Vivobook s15?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, usb, asus

I bought the Asus vivobook s15 and I got the iso of 18.04 onto my USB drive. First I had a lot of issues as when I chose something in the boot menu from the USB drive, either try or install, I got a black screen. No Splash said that it couldn't find a medium with a live distro.

I tried a lot of other solutions and finally got it working with version 19.04 Install (safe graphics) and the grub options `nosetmode`, `nolapic`, `acpi=off` and `vga=normal`. It installed and then I needed to restart, but it didn't boot; it just stayed in the splash screen, and that's where I'm at. The no splash error is

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
-Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
 -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
-Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=c0ac404a-4cb8-b308-f66e4b264e71 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu7) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Other solutions say to boot test mode from usb and fix stuff there, but the thing is that that also doesn't work like I explained before.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be problems with the graphics drivers (typical for Ubuntu and Linux in general).
Try to install the correct drivers. Be sure to use the open source versions, otherwise Ubuntu will cause even more problems.
If that doesn't work, try a different kernel.
Sometimes the graphics drivers work better with another kernel version and are installed correctly, then every kernel should be able to use the graphics card correctly.
Try to install some older and some newer kernels and just try all of them, you will surely succeed sometime.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try version 19.10. I have successfully installed Xubuntu 19.10 in a VivoBook S15 X530UF with GeForce MX130.